# Why do i have to shift - right / left key to open and close folders in nautilus, eclipse, etc.?

Tags: nautilus, keyboard, shortcut-keys

In windows, you could navigate tree menus with left/right keys, now in ubuntu 11.04 (and perhaps previous versions?) i have to hold the shift key while i do that, its quite annoying, any way to configure this?

Edit:I've attached a picture indicating the problem:

[image]

So in windows, with the focus on the circled element, I could tap the "right key" and it would open up this folder. In ubuntu, in eclipse, nautilus, etc, i have to hold down shift and the right key to get the same behaviour.

Comment: I don't understand that question. Please edit your question to describe it more detailed.

Comment: @jo-erlend he's asking if the windows folder tree navigation thing can be done here - in Tree View, you can expand/collapse the tree by using the right or left keys respectively. He wants that functionality in Ubuntu... but i dont think you can :P

Comment: chrismarx, what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 11.04 (natty) ----

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4747264/82216 for some workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

I think it boils down to this root issue in GTK: ["Please add common keybindings for the TreeView"](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105895). The [reply from a developer](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105895#c4):

> The arrow keys are already being used in GtkTreeView to move the focus
>   rectangle over the horizontal axis.

This issue was opened in 2003, the last substantial comments are also some years old, so I doubt it will be fixed soon...

Currently you can expand a folder using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You can press <kbd>Space</kbd> that the folder will open.

Comment: yes, "enter" works too, but why not right/left keys? in other applications this still works on ubuntu (sqldeveloper), oh well-

Answer (score 1):

I can set it on Ubuntu 14. not trying other versions.

```
Edit -> Preferences -> File Preferences -> Display.
```

Check "Navigate folders in a tree" in "List View". 
Now you can use left, right arrow key to open and close folders.
[image]